# Detect location of script not the page where it is called from

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if I can somehow find out the location of the script and not the page it is called from. e.g. if the page is http://xxx.yyy.com/a.htm, and I write location.href, I get that location instead of http://aaa.zzz.com/script.js where the script resides. Is it possible to get the location of the script?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Dude, I have never even THOUGHT about trying to do that...good question, why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: I am trying to allow users to straight away link to my script (from any third party site) and it uses some components from my site, which is why I need it, because users will be able to eventually download the script, and use it on different servers too.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that all resources are loaded in your script? You could always have your script call something like YUI's get utility or jQuery's getScript to make sure things are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You could loop over all the  elements in the page, calculate an absolute URI for each, then make a JSON-P request to a server side script on a server you control that will download each script and compare it to a master copy — but that would break if the script was changed in any way. A more robost solution might be achievable with a smarter comparison algorithum, but you'll never get 100% reliability (since there might be two copies of the same script included which you wouldn't be able to distinguish).

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this exact same thing just now and came up with a slightly different solution that's working well for me.  Do you own the page that the script is being referenced in?  If so, you can put an id on that script element.  Then in your javascript file, you can get that element and parse it "src" attribute for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could always grab the script tag itself and parse out the src attribute.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
    alert(scripts[i].src); 
}
```

Comment: True, but how do you know which script the code is in? I have multiple scripts on every page (well...recently I bundled them...) and you wouldn't be able to tell in which file the JavaScript was defined.

Comment: Yeah, I reached the same conclusion. David's idea of grabbing a snippet and checking that against a code repo is going to be your best shot.