# get external file source (location) using javascript

Tags: javascript

I insert an external .js file from another domain. Like this:

```
<script src="http://externaldomain.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

file.js is always the same, but it can be placed in different domains,

so I need to know what is the source of the file.

For example: file.js is in domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com.

If someone insert it like this: `<script src="http://domain1.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I want to know that the file is inserted from domain1.com

How to do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I can't find the original. The bottom line is that it is possible only using workarounds. There is no native function to do this

Comment: workarounds like adding an 'id' to '<script' and getting that id 'src' attribute?

Comment: Yes, that would work. That's pretty much what Darin's suggesting in his answer, although I think he assumed you couldn't rely on being able to change the `script` tag to add a unique identifier to it. If you can, that'll make it a lot more reliable.

Comment: @Pekka: Indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548857/how-to-get-the-location-src-of-a-javascript-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970444/detect-location-of-script-not-the-page-where-it-is-called-from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206050/extract-src-attribute-from-script-tag-and-parse-according-to-particular-matches but I know there's another, better one, with an example on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reliable way of achieving this. Basically inside this file you will need to parse the DOM, search for all the `<script>` tags and when you find the one that corresponds to the inclusion of this javascript file parse the `src` attribute to extract the domain.